# range error: maximum call stack size exceeded in google map api

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google map api, I maintain separate database(mysql) which contains location(address & latlng), when I call a single location it works, but when there is more than one location to put a marker on the map, the google dev tool says `uncaught Range error: maximum call stack size exceeded`. I've tried all the sources in the interweb, all the results are negative.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#searchbutton").click(function(){
                var category = document.getElementById("categoryinput").value;
                var place = document.getElementById("placeinput").value;
                $("#mapcontainer").css("display","block");
                $.get("http://localhost:80/rule/search.php?category="+category+"&place="+place, function(data){
                    $("#hiddeninput").val(data);
                    //Initialize the Google Maps
                    var geocoder;
                    var map;
                    var markersArray = [];
                    var infos = [];
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    var myOptions = {
                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                          zoom: 9
                        };
                    //Load the Map into the map_canvas div
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), myOptions);
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), myOptions);

                    //Initialize a variable that the auto-size the map to whatever you are plotting
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    //Initialize the encoded string       
                    var encodedString;
                    //Initialize the array that will hold the contents of the split string
                    var stringArray = [];
                    //Get the value of the encoded string from the hidden input
                    encodedString = document.getElementById("hiddeninput").value;
                    //Split the encoded string into an array the separates each location
                    stringArray = encodedString.split("****");

                    var x;
                    for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1)
                    {
                        var addressDetails = [];
                        var markericon = 'img/mapmarker.png';
                        var marker;
                        //Separate each field
                        addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");
                        //Load the lat, long data
                        var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
                        //Create a new marker and info window
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: lat,
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            //Content is what will show up in the info window
                            content: addressDetails[0],
                            icon: markericon
                        });
                        //Pushing the markers into an array so that it's easier to manage them
                        markersArray.push(marker);
                        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
                            closeInfos();
                            var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});
                            //On click the map will load the info window
                            info.open(map,this);
                            infos[0]=info;
                        });
                       //Extends the boundaries of the map to include this new location
                       bounds.extend(lat);
                    }
                    //Takes all the lat, longs in the bounds variable and autosizes the map
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);

                    //Manages the info windows
                    function closeInfos(){
                    if(infos.length > 0){
                      infos[0].set("marker",null);
                      infos[0].close();
                      infos.length = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

this code sends the jquery ajax request

```
    <?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');

//create connection to database MYSQL

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('locations') or exit('no db found');

$category = $_GET['category'];
$place = $_GET['place'];



if(empty($category) && empty($place)){
    echo "invalid input";
}
else{

    $searchquery ="SELECT * FROM `locationDatabase` WHERE `category`='$category'and `nagar`='$place' or `area`='$place'";
    $searchqueryexecute = mysql_query($searchquery);
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchqueryexecute)) {
        # code...

        $encodedstring = "";
        $x = 0;


        if($x == 0){
            $seperator = "";
        }
        else{
            $seperator = "****";
        }
        $encodedstring = $encodedstring.$seperator.
        "<p class='info'><b>".$rows['name'].
        "</b><br><b>".$rows['door_no'].
        "</b><br><b>".$rows['street'].
        "</b><br><b>".$rows['nagar'].
        "</b><br><b>".$rows['area'].
        "</b><br><b>".$rows['city']."-".$rows['zipcode'].
        "</b></p>&&&".$rows['latitude']."&&&".$rows['longitude'];
        $x = $x + 1;

        echo $encodedstring;    
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: What does your data look like for multiple points?

Comment: The posted code doesn't exhibit the reported error (at least when I provide the data it is expecting)

Comment: The error says it all.  You either have a bug which creates an infinite loop which calls many functions that eventually creates a stack overflow or your data is too big which causes the same thing.  If the former case, fix the bug and move on.  If the latter, then try to rewrite the code by calling setTimeout to allow the calls to be triggered by the event loop.

Comment: @geocodezip      its like am getting the data from the database through php(php code) and storing it in an input tag as its value, the value is encoded like ****door_no,street_no,area,city,zipcode&&&lat&&&long, with split() am revoming those **** to get group of addresses and again with split() removing those &&& will get the address, lat, lng seperately

Comment: am not sure whether the error is because of lat, long, or the bounds @Will

Comment: Please add a simple example of the data that generates the error in your question.  If I create a simple example that is in the format the code is expecting, it doesn't exhibit that error.  My sample is `var data = "New York, NY, USA&&&40.7127837&&&-74.0059413****Newark, NJ, USA&&&40.735657&&&-74.1723667****Baltimore, MD, USA&&&39.2903848&&&-76.6121893****Boston, MA, USA&&&42.3600825&&&-71.0588801";`, my guess is that your data is not in the right format, or is missing coordinates.

Comment: @geocodezip  my sample looks exactly the way you're sample look, after doing some search in the chrome dev tool, i figured that its not appending the ****

Comment: and i guess the problem is  with the php code

Comment: Are you missing coordinates from your database? If you include the error checking code from my answer, that will detect the issue.

Comment: the coordinates are in the database and the results are printing as i formatted in the php but without the ****. if this appends then the code wrote might work. @geocodezip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is appending an extra "****" to the end of the data string.  That causes an extra empty point to be added to the map, which makes the bounds invalid.  Either add error checking before creating the maker:

```
if (isNaN(addressDetails[1]) || isNaN(addressDetails[2])) {
  alert("invalid data point:"+x+" ("+addressDetails[1]+","+addressDetails[2]+")");
  continue;
}
```

Or remove the extra "****" from the end of the data.

Looks like your PHP should be (only echo the string to the output when it is complete):

```
$encodedstring = "";
$x = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchqueryexecute)) {
    # code...

    if($x == 0){
        $seperator = "";
    }
    else{
        $seperator = "****";
    }
    $encodedstring = $encodedstring.$seperator.
    "<p class='info'><b>".$rows['name'].
    "</b><br><b>".$rows['door_no'].
    "</b><br><b>".$rows['street'].
    "</b><br><b>".$rows['nagar'].
    "</b><br><b>".$rows['area'].
    "</b><br><b>".$rows['city']."-".$rows['zipcode'].
    "</b></p>&&&".$rows['latitude']."&&&".$rows['longitude'];
    $x = $x + 1;

}
echo $encodedstring;
```